# Why this ODE shows large values of errors in numerical solution??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As you can see in the figure, the numerical solution (RK4) vs analytical

[image]
for this function:
[image]

with exact solution :

[image]

,although the step size is increased, the error is so high when compared to exact solution.

Comment: What numerical method are you using? Also, where the $h=0.001$ line and the black line intersect, why do they not have the same slope? They really ought to have.

Comment: @Arthur
(RK4) is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exact solution does not fit the differential equation. Divide by $(t+1)^3$ to get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{y(t)}{(t+1)^3}=\frac1{(t+1)^2}
$$
then integrate to
$$
\frac{y(t)}{(t+1)^3}=-\frac1{t+1}+1\implies y(t)=t(t+1)^2.
$$
As you can see, there is no exponential involved.

The given function is more a solution to
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{y(t)}{t^2}=e^t\iff y'(t)=\frac{2y(t)}{t}+t^2e^t,~~y(1)=0
$$
(This equation is singular at $t=0$, so initial points have to be at $t\ne 0$, for instance where $(e^t-e)=0$.)